# Getting input & output from desktop with qt or c++

Tags: c++, qt

Recently I made a program by Qt(c++) to get screen resolution and show it by moving mouse. Currently, it works well but just on the MainWindow form;

How can I make it work when I move mouse on **desktop** also?

I Really appreciate you if you answer.;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get mouse input outside of the widget then you have to call [`QWidget::grabMouse()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grabMouse) and later `QWidget::releaseMouse()` when done. Bear in mind that it may not work on some operating systems or it may stop working when your widget (MainWindow on your case) loses focus. Also it may work worse with next update of operating system. That is because operating system vendors do not like spyware that spies mouse clicks or malware that locks whole desktop.

Comment: thanks @Öö Tiib. Now it works on whole over my program window.but still doesn't work on desktop when I minimize my program window.